# Java 7/Java 8 Difference: Process execution and PATH

Tags: java, java-8

I've added the following code into my application:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] commands = {"bash","-c","echo $PATH"};
Process process = rt.exec(commands);
```

When I print out the results running with Java 7, I get the path I expect. Java 8, however, returns nothing.

Was there a change in Java 8 that affects Process or environment variables?

This is how I print out the results:

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Seems to work in Java 8 for me. Can you post the code you're using to print out the `InputStream` from your `Process`?

Comment: I get the same results on both, and I also don't see any changes in the changelog indicating anything about this. Also try using input streams directly: `for (int i = process.getInputStream().read(); i != -1; i = process.getInputStream().read()) System.out.write(i);`

Comment: Its the 21st Century. Use java.lang.ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.getRuntime().

Comment: Are you wrapping this in a `try`-with-resources? Or are you wrapping this in a `try`/`catch` and if so, do you close the stream in a `finally` statement? The outcome might otherwise be arbitrary. Have you also verified the `PATH` variable **does** have content in the environment you are using with Java 8?

Comment: This is in a try-catch, and I did not close the stream in a finally statement. Why would that cause Java 8 to give me nothing while Java 7 prints out a PATH though? The PATH variable does have content. I print out ProcessBuilder.environment() and I see PATH populated correctly.

Comment: TBH I don't see how you wouldn't get *something* in this case, with a looped `readLine` invocation to the `BufferedReader`. But the proper practice is to close the stream anyway.

Comment: I presume that you are running Java 7 & Java 8 on the same machine ... and that it is a Unix / Linux / MacOSX machine ...

Comment: To follow up on Hector’s suggestion, have you tried `new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "echo $PATH").inheritIO().start().waitFor();`?  Not only will that print all the output, it will show if any error is occurring.

Comment: Yes, run on the same Unix machine.